# How can I edit table row using JavaScript querySelector()?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to edit data from a table.  When the edit button is pressed it will bring up an input field to edit the new value in the selected row, I tried using the code below, but nothing changes when I press the edit button.

Here is my code:

```js
const editRow = (index = "x") => {
  const tdTable = document.querySelectorAll("table > tbody > tr");

  const newRow = `
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="umur" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="address" />
      </td>
      <td colspan = 2>
        <span class="btn btn-info" onClick="saveData()">Save</span>
      </td>
    </tr>`;

  tdTable.innerHTML = newRow;
};
```

Here is what the table looks like in the browser when I press the edit button.
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if cod share the page HTML and your function `saveData()` too. It is in `saveData()` where the (changed) values need to be written back into the table.

Comment: isn't it supposed to showup the input first when i press the edit button?, the problem is when i pressed the edit button, the input box doesn't show up

Comment: I have no idea what should happen if you click the "edit" button since you have not yet shared the code for that.

Comment: the code that i share in my question that is the editRow function that directed to button Edit, it supposed to show input box and replace the old data in the row if i pressed it, but it doesn't show anything when i pressed it, the console,log show the data of the row but the edit doesn't pop up the input box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something to actually put the input values back into the original `<td>`s. Below I prepared an MCVE (minimal complete and viable example), showing how it can be done:

```js
const tb=document.querySelector("tbody"), edidel="<button>Edit</button> <button>Delete</button>";
// prepare the page first (fill in some sample data):
tb.innerHTML= [[1,"jansen",35,"medan"],
               [2,"Alfa",31,"jakarta"],
               [3,"joko",10,"solo"],
               [4,"eko cahyonto",20,"NTB"]].map(r=>
  "<tr><td>"+r.join("</td><td>")+"</td><td>"+edidel+"</td></tr>" ).join("\n");
  
tb.onclick=ev=>{
  [...ev.target.closest("tr").children].forEach((td,i)=>{ const btn=ev.target.textContent;
    if (btn==="Edit") 
      td.innerHTML=i<4?'<input type="text" value="'+td.textContent+'" data-orig="'+td.textContent+'">'
                      :'<button>Save</button> <button>Cancel</button>';
    else if (["Save","Cancel"].includes(btn))
      td.innerHTML=i<4?(btn==="Save"?td.children[0].value:td.children[0].dataset.orig)
                      :edidel;    
  })
}
```

```css
input {width:50px}
```

```html
<table>
<thead><tr><th>No</th><th>Nama</th><th>Umur</th><th>Alamat</th><th>CRUD</th></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

The first 7 lines of code simply prepare a small table on which we can work. The actual script then starts with a "delegated click event attachment" on the first `<tbody>` element of the page (which happens to be our test table). This means, we can add or remove table records and don't have to worry about attaching events to the newly created buton elements any more.

An action will only happen, if the clicked element has an ´.textContent` of either "Edit", "Save" or "Cancel" (an action for the "Delete" button has not yet been defined but can easily be added).

Depending on the actual clicked button some action on the `<TD>` elements directly before the button will be performed:

- when going into "Edit"-mode the `td.textContent` of each `<td>` is copied into a newly created `<input type="text">` element and is also save in its `data-orig` attribute, in case we want to click on "Cancel" later on.
- "Save" will copy the `.value` of each `<td>`s first child (the `<input>` element) back to its parent `td.innerHTML` attribute.
- in case "Cancel" was clicked, the `<input>`'s `.dataset.orig` value is put back into the `td.innerHTML` attribute.

Comment: i have solved using my own code, but it seems ur code give me new insight, thnx a lot sir appreaciate ur reply

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript is a case-sensitive language.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Is-JavaScript-a-case-sensitive-language#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20is%20a%20case%2Dsensitive,convey%20different%20meanings%20in%20JavaScript.)

try fixing the uppercase onClick to onclick, as the [example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp): `<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>`

Comment: the button works, but the input does'nt replace the td